# Reporting Services Deployment times out and report manager URL just hangs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, reporting-services-2012

I have been running Reporting Services on the same server for a couple of years. Our IT team say no changes have been made to the server, but suddenly I cannot deploy reports (they timeout) and when I access via the url http:\server\reports or "http:\server\reportserver" it just hangs and I never get an error. We cannot run reports.

I can run reports via the Visual Studio data tools but I cannot deploy them.

I have tried rebooting the server and restarting the Reporting services & sql server services.

Any ideas ? How can I troubleshoot this? The log files don't seem to be much help.

Thanks
PJC

Comment: Is the RS service running on the server? Also, you can restart the service safely without affecting anything else, as it's inaccessible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check here.

1. Make sure you can access the report server and report manager. (You can get the url from the SSRS configuration manager)
2. Clear the logs and retry your attempt. If a connection can be made to report server and there is something else causing the issue then you should see evidence in the log file. The log file is \Reporting Service\LogFiles.
3. If you don't see anything in the log files in step 2 or can't make a connection in step 1 above then look into the IIS log files and troubleshoot your issue from a IIS standpoint. Can you see your incoming request? Should you be using https?
4. If you cannot see your incoming request from step 3 above then it is likely a network issue.

Comment: I cannot access the report server or report manager. I get a login screen.

Comment: Windows authentication login?